# Escaping quotation marks in f string interpolation

Tags: scala, string-interpolation

I can't get to include quotation marks in the following string interpolator:

```
f"foo ${math.abs(-0.9876f)*100}%1.1f%%"
```

The output is

```
foo 98.8%
```

Now the desired output is

```
foo "98.8%"
```

Inserting `\"` doesn't work, only produces "unclosed string literal" errors.

Comment: You can use multi-line strings: `f"""foo "${math.abs(-0.9876f)*100}%1.1f%""""`

Comment: Ah right. I thought that was restricted to the `raw` method, didn't know these were independent. thanks

Comment: If you post that as answer, I can accept and close

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert double quotes into String with interpolation in scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21086263/how-to-insert-double-quotes-into-string-with-interpolation-in-scala)

Comment: The following does not work, any help: line = f'list(\'\')\n'. The single quoation will not be escaped and not shown.

Comment: for python 3: https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#python-f-strings-the-pesky-details

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Seems that [this problem wouldn't be fixed](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6476). You can use one of the following workarounds:

1. multi-line strings:

   `f"""foo "${math.abs(-0.9876f)*100}%1.1f%""""`
2. `\042`:

   `f"foo \042${math.abs(-0.9876f)*100}%1.1f%\042"`
3. `${'"'}`:

   `f"foo ${'"'}${math.abs(-0.9876f)*100}%1.1f%${'"'}"`